# Discriminated union in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, pycharm, mypy, discriminated-union

Imagine I have a base class and two derived classes. I also have a factory method, that returns an object of one of the classes. The problem is, mypy or IntelliJ can't figure out which type the object is. They know it can be both, but not which one exactly. Is there any way I can help mypy/IntelliJ to figure this out WITHOUT putting a type hint next to the `conn` variable name?

```
import abc
import enum
import typing


class BaseConnection(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def sql(self, query: str) -> typing.List[typing.Any]:
        ...


class PostgresConnection(BaseConnection):

    def sql(self, query: str) -> typing.List[typing.Any]:
        return "This is a postgres result".split()

    def only_postgres_things(self):
        pass


class MySQLConnection(BaseConnection):

    def sql(self, query: str) -> typing.List[typing.Any]:
        return "This is a mysql result".split()

    def only_mysql_things(self):
        pass


class ConnectionType(enum.Enum):
    POSTGRES = 1
    MYSQL = 2


def connect(conn_type: ConnectionType) -> typing.Union[PostgresConnection, MySQLConnection]:
    if conn_type is ConnectionType.POSTGRES:
        return PostgresConnection()
    if conn_type is ConnectionType.MYSQL:
        return MySQLConnection()


conn = connect(ConnectionType.POSTGRES)
conn.only_postgres_things()
```

Look at how IntelliJ handles this:
[image]

As you can see both methods: `only_postgres_things` and `only_mysql_things` are suggested when I'd like IntelliJ/mypy to figure it out out of the type I'm passing to the `connect` function.

Comment: Are you absolutely committed to that factory API? Both `enum.Enum` and `typing.TypedDict` can offer something more natural for what you’re trying to do.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: You have a one-to-one relation between an enum value and a class. Looking at this a bit more, I'm not quite understanding why you wouldn't just access the various subclasses directly from a module instead (`import conn_module; conn_module.PostgresConnection()`), instead of going through a boilerplate factory function `connect`.

Answer (score 6):

Since the purpose of your `ConnectionType` class is apparently to make your API more readable and user-friendly rather than to use any specific features of `Enum`, you don't really have to make it an `Enum` class.

Instead, you can create a regular class with each connection type assigned to a class variable of a user-friendly name, so that you can type the return value of the `connect` function with a type variable and type the parameter with the type of the type variable. Use a type alias to make the type of the type variable even more readable:

```
class ConnectionTypes:
    POSTGRES = PostgresConnection
    MYSQL = MySQLConnection

Connection = typing.TypeVar('Connection', PostgresConnection, MySQLConnection)
# or make it bound to the base class:
# Connection = typing.TypeVar('Connection', bound=BaseConnection)
ConnectionType: typing.TypeAlias = type[Connection]

def connect(type_: ConnectionType) -> Connection:
    if type_ is ConnectionType.POSTGRES:
        return PostgresConnection()
    if type_ is ConnectionType.MYSQL:
        return MySQLConnection()
```

[image: Use a regular class in combination with a type variable.]

Comment: without any imports from `typing` in Python 3.12:  `def connect[T: type(PostgresConnection, MySQLConnection)](conn_type: T) -> T: return conn_type()`

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) combined with [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal), like so:

```
@typing.overload
def connect(type_: typing.Literal[ConnectionType.POSTGRES]) -> PostgresConnection:
    ...

@typing.overload
def connect(type_: typing.Literal[ConnectionType.MYSQL]) -> MySQLConnection:
    ...

def connect(type_):
    if type_ is ConnectionType.POSTGRES:
        return PostgresConnection()
    if type_ is ConnectionType.MYSQL:
        return MySQLConnection()
```

I replaced `type` with `type_` so you don't shadow the builtin, and it's idiomatic to compare enum values using `is` instead of `==`.

Comment: I'm still getting Union :(

Comment: @mnowotka could you explain where are you "still getting Union"? This [works](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=fbcc235af1e99cc29619bbe77fb6ee57) for me with `mypy`...

Comment: @SUTerliakov - when I hover over conn variable in PyCharm the tooltip says this is of type Union. When I type dot next to conn the suggestion still contains both methods as described in the question.

Comment: @mnowotka That's probably Pycharm bug/limitation and not a typing issue then. I'm not sure that in Pycharm autocomplete and type checking are coupled, let's wait for somebody who has more Pycharm experience to clarify this.

Comment: @SUTerliakov AFAIK PyCharm uses mypy under the hood.

Comment: @mnowotka at least there is Pyright, which is used in pylance for type checking instead of `mypy`. I doubt so: "Pyright is the open-source type checker which Pylance uses under the hood to provide its functionality."

Comment: PyCharm doesn't use mypy under the hood. PyCharm has its own code analysis and code insight systems, and includes its own type checker which may not conform with mypy's code analysis. PyCharm's code insight's relationship with its type analysis system is like VSCode's pylance's relationship with pyright. If you want mypy to be your linter in PyCharm, you can install the mypy real time linter plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11086-mypy).